# Dependency property bindings not working for class unless I make it a static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, silverlight, prism

I have a custom class and my dependency properties won't work with bindings unless I declare the class as a static resource.
My xaml:

```
<sdk:Frame prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainContentRegion">
    <sdk:Frame.ContentLoader>
        <myLibrary:RegionNavigationContentLoader
            RegionManager="{Binding RegionManager}"
            RegionName="MainContentRegion" />
    </sdk:Frame.ContentLoader>
</sdk:Frame>
```

My custom loader class:

```
public class RegionNavigationContentLoader : FrameworkElement, INavigationContentLoader
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegionManagerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RegionManager", typeof(IRegionManager), typeof(RegionNavigationContentLoader), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public IRegionManager RegionManager {
        get { return (IRegionManager)GetValue(RegionManagerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RegionManagerProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegionNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RegionName", typeof(string), typeof(RegionNavigationContentLoader), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public string RegionName {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RegionNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RegionNameProperty, value); }
    }

    ...
}
```

It does, however, work fine when I declare the loader as a resource and then pass it in as a staticresource binding on the frame.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <myLibrary:RegionNavigationContentLoader x:Key="RegionLoader"
        RegionManager="{Binding RegionManager}"
        RegionName="MainContentRegion" />
</Grid.Resources>

<sdk:Frame prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainContentRegion"
    ContentLoader="{StaticResource RegionLoader}"/>
```

This isn't a big deal but I want to know why. Anyone know?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? And if you run under the debugger, do any binding errors show up in the Output window?

Comment: Joe - there weren't any binding errors reported. The setters on my properties just weren't hit when I stepped them in debugger.

Comment: Adam, note that setters won't be hit anyway even if it does work.  Bindings assign values to Dependency properties via `SetValue` bypassing the standard .NET property setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContentLoader` property is merely expecting an implementation fo `INavigationContentLoader`.

It is not expecting to receive a `FrameworkElement` or even a `DependencyObject`, its only expecting a plain old ordinary class that happens to implement a specific interface.  As result it just references the provided instance it does nothing else with it.

In turn this means when an instance of your `RegionNavigationContentLoader` is directly constructed and assigned along with your binding the binding can't find a DataContext, its search for a DataContext ends right there at `RegionNavigationContentLoader` because it can't find a parent.

On the other hand when you construct your instance and add it to a `ResourceDictionary` (which is a DependencyObject) which is in turn owned by the `UserControl` which does have a data context the binding can find what its looking for.  This same object is subsequently assigned to the `Frame` by the static resource.

BTW, are you sure you need to derive from `FrameworkElement` would `DependencyObject` not do?

Comment: Thank you Anthony. Inheriting from DependencyObject instead of FrameworkElement makes it work. Now I don't fully understand why. Since FrameworkElement inherits from UIElement which inherits from DependencyObject. What is the difference? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @AdamD: Well thats a result!  I wasn't expecting that so I can only speculate why.  When the target of a binding is not a `FrameworkElement` the `BindingExpression` asks the runtime to create a special `FrameworkElement` to wrap the target object in.  Whether that special instance of `FrameworkElement` can do what a standard one can't I don't know.  I can't see how.  Perhaps the Xaml parser itself has a part to play but as it stands I can't fathom the mechanism that would make this work. Very curious.